# Cannot create new project via ng cli using "ng new" command

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

Actually I've used angular in windows and I didn't faced this problem after updated to ng 4. But when i'm trying this to ubuntu after updating to ng 4, I'm facing this issue while trying to create a new app using `ng new` command. See the below image. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UMxj.png)

Comment: The trick is to read the error message: You cannot use ng new inside an angular CLI project. It's very clear. You're already inside an angular CLI projet, and you're trying to create a project inside that project. Don't do that, as the message says.

Comment: Is there already a `my-app` directory present?

Comment: but, actually i'm not in inside of any angular project and i never created any in this OS yet!

Comment: @nitind nope, nothing is there, http://imgur.com/qEcb064

Comment: This is a time for `ls -a` if ever there was one.

Comment: @nitind still no extra folder or files found on desktop. But it works on other drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have an npm project (a `package.json` file) within your desktop folder or in the path above. Either delete or move that project or put your new project in a different directory. see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2818#issuecomment-257964822

Comment: Nope, I cannot create on other folders too: http://imgur.com/Km8VxZW :(

Edit - 1: Let me search for any.

Comment: It goes all the way up. So if you try `ng new project` within `~/dir1/dir2` and you have a package.json in `dir1`, it will still fail. In your console, run `pwd` and check all directories

Comment: Yep, `ng new` command works on other drives. I'm trying the way metioned on the github source. Thanks BTW.